# Do a multilanguage application?

Tags: d, phobos

I would like to know how do a multilanguage application. It seem it is possible by using flag -J but they are no document for this feature.
link given in this page http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/dmd-linux.html seem to be wrong

if you can do a little example, will be nice. Something for detect at runtime or not if not possibe with usage -J flag

thanks

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by a multilanguage application -- the `-J` flag is for the `import(some_string)` expression, passed to DMD (which is just a compiler).

Project management is outside the scope of DMD.

Comment: someyhing like gnu gettex multilanguage as (english, deutch, french ..)

Comment: @bioinfornatics: The `-J` flag has nothing to do with Internationalization and localization.

Comment: if i want detect localization at rutime and not at compile time?

Comment: thanks @Mehrdad . I have try a minimal code i assume is posix only it could be improved

Answer (score 1):

The `-J` flags give DMD the root paths to use for [Import Expressions](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/expression.html#ImportExpression). You might be able to use this as *part* of some kind of [i18n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) system but it's designed for importing arbitrary data blobs at compile time.

---

Edit: From memory:

```
void main() {
  // the import expression resolves at compile 
  // time to the contents of the named file.
  stirng s = import("some_data_file.txt");
  writef("%s", s);
}
```

Compiled like this:

```
echo Hello World > some_data_file.txt
dmd code.d -J ./
```

will make produce a program that will print this when run:

```
Hello World
```

This is the long, short and total of what the import expression is for and the sole use for the `-J` flag is to control the path's the import expression reads from.

Comment: So it is better use gettex for this? or they are another way in D programming.

Comment: It's not better or worse or anything to do with, around, or related to the -J flag.

Comment: thanks @BCS . I have try a minimal code i assume is posix only it could be improved

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @BCS

So without -J flag, for use localization i have do:

```
module localisation;

import std.string;
import std.stdio    : write, File, exists, StdioException, lines;
import std.array    : split;
import std.process  : getenv;
import std.exception: enforce, enforceEx;

struct Culture{
    string[string]  data = null;
    string          name = null;
    public static Culture opCall( string[string] data, string name ){ // Constructor
        Culture res;
        res.data = data;
        res.name = name;
        return res;
    }
}

static Culture culture = Culture(null, null);

Culture getLocalization(in string language){
    string fileName             = null;
    string name                 = null;
    string[string] localization = null;

    if ( exists("messages_"~ language ~ ".properties") ){
        fileName    = "messages" ~ language ~ ".properties";
        name        = language;
    }
    else if ( language.length >= 5 ){
        if ( language[2] == '-' ){
            fileName    = "messages_" ~ language[0..2] ~ "_" ~ language[4..5] ~ ".properties";
            name        = language[0..2] ~ "_" ~ language[4..5];
        }
        else{
            fileName    = "messages_" ~ language[0..5] ~ ".properties";
            name        = language[0..5];
        }
    }
    // Thrown an exception if is null
    enforce( fileName, "Unknow Culture format: " ~  language);
    // Thrown an exception if name is null
    enforce( name, "Error: name is null");
    // Thrown an exception if is path do not exist
    enforceEx!StdioException( exists( fileName ), "Cannot open file " ~ fileName ~ ", do not exist or is not include with -J flag" );

    File fileCulture = File( fileName, "r" );

    foreach(string line; lines(fileCulture)){
        string[] result = split(line, "=");
        localization[ result[0] ] = result[1];
    }
    return Culture( localization, name);
}


void main ( string[]  args ){
    string[string] localization = null;
    string  language            = getenv("LANG");
    culture                     = getLocalization( language );
}
```

and each files are named like: message_`<language>`.properties. Where in properties files is something like:

```
key1=value
key2=value
```

i split string by using "=" character and put in a hashmap. For get right statement just use the key

Comment: the `-J` flag will have no effect what so ever on that code. The `-J` flag has no more to do with localization than the `printf` function does. You seem to be seeing a connection where there is none. Could you please post a link (and ideally a quote) to whatever it is that gave you the totally mistaken idea that there is any connection between the `-J` flag and localization. That way the documentation can be fixed to avoid whatever it was that cause this confusion.

Comment: i have seen in dwt2 project https://bitbucket.org/kntroh/dwt2-with-d2/overview. it use -J flag for ressource in ressource they are `<language>_<region>`.properties files (locale). and they are something for work with in https://bitbucket.org/kntroh/dwt2-with-d2/src/d00e8db0a568/base/src/java/nonstandard/Locale.d . The problem is std.process.getenv is at runtime and import(..) compile time

Comment: Yup, `import()`/`-J` can't help you if you don't know what files you need till runtime. The solution is to grab them *all* at compile time and select one of them at run time. OTOH this doesn't do you any good if you don't have them all at compile time so you might want to put in a default handler that uses the normal libs to try and load files from disk at runtime for anything you don't cover at compile time. -- BTW it seems the confusion was that your question didn't really have much to do with localization beyond using it as a motivating example.

Comment: yes i had a confusion about -J flag now i understand beter . Thanks a lot for take time and explains.

Comment: just for understand, i want in fact just have a multi-localization program, who choose right language at runtime. If i use -J flag i can give directly the executable if not i need give in more locale file. So 3 possibilities: -J/import + choose at runtime like you said; do not use -J/import only runtime like show my code; use getex.